# new WSUS server and old computers

Tags: wsus

My company we changed domain so we disjoined all computers from the old domain and rejoined to the new domain. We setup a new WSUS server and it synchronized a lot of updates, now I am approving them in sequence.

All my computers have Office 2007 SP3 installed but in WSUS I see SP3 update is needed from all computers, and it is wrong. I also can see that SP1 and SP2 are needed and it is very strange.

The question is: can I approve these updates without problems? What will happen when clients will download this specific update? Will they ignore it since it is already installed? Or can I expect strange behavior?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that SP3 is installed? This is strange, it should not list them, only if they are not installed. So if it lists SP1, SP2 and SP3, it should be an RTM install.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure SP3 is installed an all clients. What should be an RTM install? Windows Server or Office?

Comment: RTM = Release to Manufacturing = "Original" install without SP

Comment: Office 2007 was installed as "SP0" version and then updated with service packs. Also on new clients we setup, we install 2007 SP0 and then manually install SP3 before connecting the client to the network.

Comment: By SP0 do you mean RTM? I've never heard of it being called SP0.

Comment: Yes, I mean the "first sold" version, without any service pack. However, I think you got reason: also if I see SP3 needed, if I explore its details in wsus, I see that for all machines it is "already installed", so it won't be installed again if approved. In short, I approved all  this kind of updates without having problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can approve the updates without fear of any issues. If somehow WSUS provides you with the option to approve an update that really isn't applicable, the result will be the exact same as trying to install the standalone version of that update on the client systems - it just won't work. I would approve them and only worry if you start seeing installation errors.